# Android Studio не удается скачать aapt2

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle

**1.** при попытке скачивания, выдает такие ошибки

> ! 08:35:47.666 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] 
>   Loading **https:/ /dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.1-5435860/aapt2-3.5.1-5435860-windows.jar**
>   08:35:47.666 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] 
>   Constructing external resource: **https:/ /dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.1-5435860/aapt2-3.5.1-5435860-windows.jar**
>   08:35:47.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Download **https:/ /dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.1-5435860/aapt2-3.5.1-5435860-windows.jar'** started
>   08:35:47.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: **https:/ /dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.1-5435860/aapt2-3.5.1-5435860-windows.jar**
>   08:35:47.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP GET: **https:/ /dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.1-5435860/aapt2-3.5.1-5435860-windows.jar**
>   08:35:47.668 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
>   08:35:47.668 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
>   08:35:47.668 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {tls}->**http:/ /127.0.0.1:8086->https:/ /dl.google.com:443]**[total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
>   08:35:47.668 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 18][route: {tls}->**http:/ /127.0.0.1:8086->https:/ /dl.google.com:443]**[total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 20]
>   08:35:47.668 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {tls}->**http:/ /127.0.0.1:8086->https:/ /dl.google.com:443**
>   08:35:47.668 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to **/127.0.0.1:8086**
>   08:35:49.708 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-18: **Shutdown connection**

не понятно еще почему подключается к 127.0.0.1:8086, хотя нет никаких настроек прокси

**2.** скаченные вручную компоненты, не принимает по отсутствию стандартных мета-данных

> ! 08:35:47.662 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/C:/Users/Psu/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.1-5435860/aapt2-3.5.1-5435860.pom
>   08:35:47.663 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/C:/Users/Psu/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.1-5435860/aapt2-3.5.1-5435860-windows.jar
>   08:35:47.663 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Found artifact but no meta-data for module 'com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.1-5435860' in repository 'injected_offline_android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01', using default meta-data.

Answer (score 1):

в gradle service directory, в моем случае C:/Users/{username}/.gradle, находится gradle.properties файл глобальных настроек, там был прописан proxy адрес 127.0.0.1:8086.
убрал их и все заработало

не знаю как там они появились